# Javascript Code inside input value

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I use Maxminds GEOIP tool and just call this after the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

To print out the City and State I just paste this into the HTML doc:

```
<script>document.write(geoip_city());</script>
<script>document.write(geoip_region());</script>
```

I want to pass those values in hidden inputs that I can submit and assign to variables.  What I want is this, but obviously the syntax is way off:

```
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="<script>document.write(geoip_city());</script>" />
```

I've tried searching for it here but couldn't find an answer, can anybody help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would write this (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com)) as:

```
var geo_city   = geoip_city();
var geo_region = geoip_region();

$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#city").val(geo_city);

});

<input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="" />
```

This code will take the variable `geo_city` and put it in your hidden text field that has the ID city.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a class to the elements you want populated by the geoip service, such as the obvious `geoip` class-name, and using a map of the geoip functions to populate the values of the hidden `input` elements based on their name, such as (untested, and, without a public API, untestable unfortunately):

```
var geoipMap {
    'city' : geoip_city(),
    'region' : geoip_region(),
    'country' : geoip_country() // and so on...
};

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    geoipInputs = [];

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].className.indexOf('geoip') !== -1) {
        geoipInputs.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, len = geoipInputs; i < len; i++) {
    geoipInputs[i].value = geoipMap[geoipInputs[i].name];
}
```